# How can I trim metal window wells after lowering the grade around them?

Tags: windows, metal

I just had a new stamped patio poured. We lowered the grading so now the widow wells are higher than the patio. I want to install window well covers but need to cut down the window wells (below the cement) what would be the best tool for the job?

Comment: I'm confused what needs to be cut and why, if the window wells are above the patio.  Perhaps a photo...

Answer (score 4):

Are you taking about one of these things?

[image]

If so, you might not want to cut it down. The lip should be a bit higher than the surrounding grade so that rainwater doesn't run in to the well.

If you don't cut it, you might be able to decorate it.

[image]

However, if you really want to cut it then you can use a reciprocating saw. If the metal is too thick, you might need to use a cut-off wheel on an angle grinder.